# What's the best tool to install a rivnut into a PVC tube?

Tags: rivets

What tool do I need to use in order to install a rivnut (rivnut PN with slotted shank) into a PVC tube (fence rail)?

Looking for a tool for infrequent use that works well and isn't of questionable quality. Must be something that can be ordered online.

Comment: Hey Hal, Welcome to the site.  There's really just one type of tool to install a rivnut and they work like a tool to install a rivet.  This is more of a shopping question, and those are not a good fit for our site.  Check out the [help](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page for more info.

Comment: Their are several brands of rivnuts some don’t require a tool, you drill the hole and use a screw to pull them into the hole, the splines on the nut hold them in place. This is the style I use when I have a blind hole.

Comment: You can find lots of diy rivnut setter videos out there. Essentially, you have the rivnut, a couple of lock washers, a nut that runs freely on your bolt, a couple more washers, and a bolt through all of it. Hold the nut with a wrench and use an impact driver to run the bolt in until the rivnut is set. My only concern for you is the strength of the rivnut in pvc.